Getting error FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory while starting the angular project
My Angular project has been upgraded from Angular 6 to Angular 16. I updated my Angular project by carefully following the Angular update guide. After the update, I'm encountering an error attached below while attempting to launch my Angular project with Angular/CLI 16. I have updated all my libraries. I am using Windows OS and the RAM is 40 GB. I tried to increase the heap space by adding the variable NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096 into the Environment variable.
"⠏ Generating browser application bundles (phase: sealing)...
<--- Last few GCs --->
[32040:0496B8F8]    25141 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 688.7 (790.4) -> 688.6 (748.6) MB, 424.9 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.511, current mu = 0.002) last resort GC in old space requested
[32040:0496B8F8]    25548 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 688.6 (748.6) -> 688.7 (740.9) MB, 406.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.335, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested
<--- JS stacktrace --->
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"
Screenshot of Error
Below is my package.json file
{
  "name": "angular-16pro",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --configuration production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/localize": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.12",
    "@circlon/angular-tree-component": "^10.0.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^1.5.2",
    "@ngx-pwa/local-storage": "^6.0.0",
    "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.8.0",
    "angular-chosen-localytics": "^1.8.0",
    "angular-local-storage": "^0.7.1",
    "angular-localstorage": "^1.1.5",
    "angular-tree-component": "^7.0.2-beta1",
    "angular-webstorage-service": "^1.0.2",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^2.9.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "export-to-csv": "^0.2.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ng-lz-string": "^1.5.3",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.9",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^5.2.6",
    "ng2-ion-range-slider": "^2.0.0",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.8.3",
    "ng5-slider": "^1.2.6",
    "ngx-csv": "^0.3.2",
    "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^2.4.2",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.2.0",
    "nouislider": "^15.7.1",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.13",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "^16.2.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "ngx-typeahead": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3"
  }
}

Please let me know the fixes.Thanks in Advance.

Have you updated your nodejs version to one that is compatible with Angular 16? See https://angular.io/guide/versions

@Cuzy, yes i have updated and currently, i am using 16.20.0 node js version.
